# How to make a selection from a dropdown using Python Selenium 4.1 if the dropdown is not a Select element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, select

I am trying to do some automation for a work system where we need to close tickets that has been completed by a Tech.  The website does make use of Shadow Dom (User-agent) code, but I have disabled that in the Web Developer tools.

I am using Pycharm and have Selenium 4.1 installed.

The Dropdown box I want to make a selection is names "Failure code" onscreen, and I want to select (at this point) any of the options.

I can actually find the Dropdown Element and even click it, but I dont actually UNDERSTAND how THAT is done as the code never select a "SELECT" - element"
What I cannot get right, is to make a selection from the Dropdown box (or even clear it).

Don't worry about the sleep timers in my code, they are just there so I can follow what is happening when the program runs.

I think there is a lot of scripting happening as well.
Unfortunately I cannot post the link to the website as its a work related system.

## ======= The IMPORTS ==========

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

## My Code dealing with the Dropdown box

```
    # FAILURE CODE DROPDOWN BOX
    # ==========================
    try :

        failure_code_boxWait = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#fields_1056_chosen > a")))
```

#(I dont understand why this actually works)

```
        failure_code_box = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#fields_1056_chosen > a")
        time.sleep(3)

        failure_code_box.click()  
#THIS HAPPENS ONSCREEN successfully

        time.sleep(3)

        failure_code_box.clear() 
#This Fails with "INVALID ELEMENT STATE"

        time.sleep(5)
        #  quit()

        select = Select(failure_code_box)   

#The above code fails if I take away the above code that fails with :     UnexpectedTagNameException(f"Select only works on <select> elements, not on {webelement.tag_name}")


        select.select_by_index(2)
        time.sleep(3)

        print("SOMTHING GOOD Happened!!")
        quit()

        time.sleep(.25)
        # print(f"Failure Code : [{failure_code}] ")
        failure_code_box.send_keys(failure_code, Keys.TAB)
        print("SUCCESS : I SEND the TAB KEY")
        time.sleep(5)
        quit()
    except TimeoutException:
        print("ERROR:Could not find the FAILURE CODE BOX ?")
        # I get this error if I do not use the 'a' tag in the CSS Selector
        quit()
```

## Here is the code from the WEB PAGE

```
<div class="form-group form-group-1056 form-group-fieldtype_entity form-group-entity-41">
                            <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="fields_1056"><span class="required-label">*</span>Failure Code</label>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                              <div id="fields_1056_rendered_value"><select name="fields[1056]" id="fields_1056" class="form-control chosen-select input-medium field_1056 required" style="display: none;"><option value="">Please Select</option><option value="2">DIRTUNKEMP</option><option value="3">BROKEN</option><option value="4">DAMAGED</option><option value="5">FALSEALARM</option><option value="6">LEAKING</option><option selected="" value="7">NOTWORKING</option><option value="201">Wear and Tear</option><option value="683">NA</option></select><div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" title="" id="fields_1056_chosen" style="width: 100%;"><a class="chosen-single">
  <input class="chosen-focus-input" type="text" autocomplete="off">
  <span>NOTWORKING</span>
  <div><b></b></div>
</a>
<div class="chosen-drop">
  <div class="chosen-search">
    <input class="chosen-search-input" type="text" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
</div></div>
          <label id="fields_1056-error" class="error" for="fields_1056"></label>
          <script>
              $("#fields_1056").on("change", function(e) { 
                  $("#fields_1056-error").hide(); 
              });
          </script>
            <script>    
                function prepare_add_edit_button_1056()
                {
                    let value = $("#fields_1056").val()
                                            
                    if($("#fields_1056").attr("multiple")=="multiple" || $("#btn_submodal_edit_item_1056").length==0)
                    {
                        $("#btn_submodal_edit_item_1056").attr("data-item-id",0).hide()
                        return false
                    }                                        

                    if(value>0)
                    {
                        $("#btn_submodal_add_item_1056").hide()
                        $("#btn_submodal_edit_item_1056").attr("data-item-id",value).show()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#btn_submodal_add_item_1056").show()
                        $("#btn_submodal_edit_item_1056").attr("data-item-id",0).hide()

                    }
                }
                
                $(function(){
                    prepare_add_edit_button_1056()
                        
                    $("#fields_1056").change(function (e) {                            
                        prepare_add_edit_button_1056()                            
                    });
                });
            </script>
                </div>
                          
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to help you without concrete resource, however, I'll provide general recommendations how to select dropdown element that is not a select.

Select class can proceed only native dropdowns with `select` and `option` tags.

To proceed custom dropdown, you need to know dropdown options container selector, so launch test in debug mode and open dev tools.

Put debug line after clicking on dropdown box and launch the test.
In test you:

1. Wait for visibility of dropdown box (like you did)

```py
failure_code_boxWait = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#fields_1056_chosen > a")))
```

2. Click on it

```py
failure_code_boxWait.click()
```

3. (There debugger is stopped) Search for dropdown box selector in dev tools. For example, by text of dropdown options.
4. Wait for dropdown container visibility.

```py
dropdown_container = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"locatorFromStep3")))
```

5. Get the list of dropdown options

```py
options = dropdown_container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'dropdownOptionsSelectorFromStep3')
```

6. Process dropdown options by selection condition (for example, click by index)

```py
options[2].click()
```

7. Wait for dropdown container invisibility

```py
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element(dropdown_container))
```

Comment: Thank you.  That definitely put me on the right track.   After clicking the initial element, and with a debug stop on the next line,  I was able to identify an input field that I could "send_keys" to, to select the correct option, and then TAB to a next field.  Very helpful. THANK you.